# Mailing by PHP with HTML format with form/page

Tags: php, email

I am sending mail to mail id with a form/page in a **html** format. Page is showing on mail id but my **css** is not applying on mail and images are not showing. Only text is showing without CSS and Images.

Comment: Some quick suggestions on webmail.  First, all your CSS should be inline as most popular email clients strip all code outside of the BODY tag.  Second, all your image paths must be full web paths, i.e. *http://mysite.com/test.gif*

Comment: I am using light view effect in mail, so I can not use inline css. I am using light view css file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display images in mail which you send, you have two ways.
1) set img srcs to your web site like this. 
http://www.....com/images/email/logo.jpg

2) send images in email.

Pros and Cons

1) If you want to send lots of emails use this way. when users opens your email images will be downloaded from your web server. the amount of email will be light.
2) If you send few emails you can use this way. email will be heavy and it will take time to send it to receipen's email server.